# iframe functionality for pasting one html into another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have my page **a.html**. I need paste into it another third-party page (**b.html**). **b.html** contains some javascript in it, which changes url (url.rewrite, history pushes and etc). I need to load it, but stay on the original page mysite/a.html.
I think of using iframes. The problem is that b.html it can contain accessing to window in its javascript (window.frames, window.top and etc), so as I understood b.html in a frame will work incorrect.
Were there any ways to solve my problem with pasting b.html with its javascript into a.html?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it almost sounds like Server Side Includes would be what you require - assuming your host supports it

Comment: No support of ssi:(